# How to position fixed a button within a jQuery mobile pannel?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile 1.4.5 to show a pannel (layer on top of content). There is a form submit button which I would like to position fixed at the bottom of the view.

This works if the layer is visible without being a pannel. As soon as I add the pannel code, the button moves to the end of the page which is large and therefore disapears out of the sight of the user.

Added pannel code which disables the fixed position:

```
data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-display="overlay"
```

Entire code:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-display="overlay"  data-position="left" style="background: #fff;width: 100%;position:absolute;top:92px;">
    <div style="padding:10px;">
        <form>
            <div style="position: fixed;bottom: 20px; z-index: 1; width: calc(100% - 20px);">
                <input type="submit" value="Suchen" data-theme="b" >
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show the css of #left-panel

Comment: it is inline the code

Comment: this current code is working fine, please share more of your code, https://jsfiddle.net/cLy28re6/

Comment: Difficult to seperate from the project. Here is a link to staging. Click with a mobile device on the button "test" inside header: http://staging.www.de.watchgurus.de/rolex/ andy:newpw2

Comment: you have to move the submit button out of the div to make it work apparently

Comment: as your parent div has position: absolute, you can't use position: fixed in it to fix an item inside it to the screen position.

Comment: I understand, however in this case there must be something else. After replacing posistion: absolute with margin-top, the button is still at the very end of the page.

Comment: for that try giving this to the popup div: height: 100%; overflow: scroll;